# how to compare current time with datetime field in db continuously?

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, datetime, automation

I'm am working on an **bootstrap website** where I have get a list of tasks to do from mysql db which starts on different times of the day.
I also have to pop up a reminder when each task is about to start. Table has 4 columns `task_id`(int), `task_name`(varchar),
`start_time`(datetime), and `details`(varchar).

I've managed to get the data from the table and display it in a table in my website,using the mysql_fetch_array loop.

I understand and am using the bootstrap modal to do the pop up of the reminder.

But I'm not sure on how to do the triggering of the pop up, and how to continuously check for tasks which match with the current time, to trigger the pop ups.

Any idea on how I can go about doing this?

Comment: do not use deprecated `mysql_*` functions; use MySQLi or PDO instead. And please, show your codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the check on each page load. And if you expect a user to stay on the same page for a long time, you can setup a timer (setInterval in JS) that will make an ajax request to check if there is a task to display

Comment: can you give me an example on how to use the setInterval to make an ajax request?

Comment: This will trigger a get request to a given URL every 5 seconds: ```setInterval(function checkTask() { $.get( "[URL]", function(data) { // do something }); }, 5000);```